# Nested Listview.builder in flutter

Tags: flutter

I tried to use nested Listview builder the data can be retrieved but it doesn't appear in the ui, I'm confused I've been looking for it but still haven't found the right solution, this my code:

```
  Widget _buildViewDataReport(BuildContext context, List<GetReport>listReport){
    return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: listReport.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _getHeader(listReport[index].header),
                    _buildWidgetSizedBox(20),
                    _getDataBody(listReport[index].data),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
    );
  }

  Widget _getHeader(List<Header>listHeader){
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('INI HEADER TIDAK MASUK LISTVIEW.BUILDER'),
        ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: listHeader.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('${listHeader[index].label} : ${listHeader[index].value}')
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `CustomScrollView` and `SliverList` instead of `ListView`. Here's an example:

```
return CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index) => Text('first list, $index'),
        childCount: 10,
      ),
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index) => Text('second list, $index'),
        childCount: 10,
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

Comment: is not working, The argument type 'Text Function(dynamic, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'.

Comment: Can you paste the code you've written and got the error? @farhan

Comment: wait, i have one question for you, so, if listview.builder is inside that listview.builder the data won't show up?

Comment: Widget _buildViewDataReport(BuildContext context, List<GetReport>listReport){
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listReport.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              _getHeader(context, listReport[index].header),
              // _buildWidgetSizedBox(20),
              // _getDataBody(context, listReport[index].data),
            ],
          );
        }
    );
  }

Comment: Widget _getHeader(BuildContext context, List<Header> listHeader){
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => Text('first list, ${listHeader[index].label}'),
            childCount: 10,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }